# Where can I find a good introduction to Haskell optimization passes?

Tags: haskell, ghc, compiler-optimization

I know the basics of Haskell compilation. I'd like to know more about the high-level (that is, before C-- code generation) optimizations done by GHC. Where is a good place to start?

Comment: ghc doc might be a good place to start.

Comment: Does GHC still have a C-- backend? I thought that was dropped - it doesn't appear here at least: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/code-generators.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [haskellwiki Performance category](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Category:Performance) and [overview page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance) is a good place to start. It contains tips on how to optimize your programs for space and speed. It has a good overview of [GHC optimization](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/GHC) and information on more specific topics: libraries to use, best practices, [how to prevent laziness from eating up your memory](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Strictness), [how to use laziness to your advantage](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Laziness), and how to use GHC-specific features (like INLINE and [RULES](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Playing_by_the_rules)), among other things.

The [GHC source](https://github.com/ghc/ghc) is also fairly straightforward to read, and there is a wide range of commentary on the entire compilation process [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/HscMain). Specifically, the `SimplCore` pass seems to implement a lot of the optimizations. There are also some good papers written by the GHC authors ([here](http://research.microsoft.com/~simonpj/Papers/comp-by-trans-scp.ps.gz), [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/inlining/index.htm), [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/rules.htm), [here](http://research.microsoft.com/~simonpj/papers/float.ps.gz), and [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/cpr/index.htm)). Finally, the GHC commentary contains a section on [exactly](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/OptOrdering) what (I think) you're looking for.

Happy reading :)

Comment: Thanks! A lot of interesting articles.